# inline-block align with text

Tags: css

I have a inline-block element and some text on the same line. They don't seem to align on the same baseline.

```
<div>
  <i class="avatar"></i>
  <span>Name</span>
</div>

i.avatar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/Cr952/ for what I mean.

Any ideas to align them? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: bottom` to `i.avatar`.

[image: Screenshot]

```
i.avatar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 2px solid black;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cr952/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Add`vertical-align:bottom` in i css

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

[image]

then use `float:left` as follow,

**CSS**

```
i.avatar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    float: left;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    float: left;
}
```